# I hate asking this because it's everywhere, but PHP code in browser

Tags: php, html, macos, apache, installation

I'm new to PHP; I'm using Mac OS X (10.8.4), I'm using PHP 5.3.15; my server API is Apache 2.0.
So, I went through the relatively painless steps of setting up Apache and installing PHP and MySQL. 
I created a pretty basic PHP test file (just a call to the info function) and it worked properly.
However, when I tried creating a basic program from a book, the PHP code appeared in the browser.
I have done the following:
Configured my httpd.conf file (the phpinfo() test works).
Reseting my Apache server via the terminal and through the web sharing button in settings
I put both the files in the Web Server folder.

Interestingly enough, of course when I just do localhost/processorder.php the file appears as it should, i.e. interpreted, not in code. 
So, my assumption is that it has something to do with my html file (??)

Anyway, 
Here's my code; thanks in advance for any advice!:

html file (orderForm.html):

```
<form action="processorder.php"
method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr 
bgcolor="#cccccc">
<td 
width="150">Item</td>
<td 
width="15">Quantity</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Tires</td>
    <td align="center">
    <input 
    type="text"
    name="tireqty" size="3"
    maxlength="3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Oil</td>
<td align="center">
<input
type="text"
name="oilqty"
size="3"
maxlength="3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spark Plugs </td>
<td align="center">
    <input 
    type="text"
    name="sparkqty"
    size="3"
    maxlength="3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input
type="submit"
value="Submit Order"
/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

php file (processorder.php):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Order Results </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Nolan Auto Parts</h1>
 <h2>Order Results</h2>
<?php
echo'<p>Order processed.</p>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: orderForm.html just change `.html` to `.php` :)

Comment: @Akam what difference would this make there isn't any php in the orderForm.html

Comment: You could try [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)... Might be more useful than your book :P...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out! :D
I'm also new to HTML, so this is what happened, for those who fall victim to the same mistake:

```
<form action=""
```

Will call the *address* of something. 
So, you can't just type whatever.php, you have to do something like

```
<form action="http://localhost/whatever.php"
```

The path of the file is important :p

Comment: the action attribute works like file paths in most operating systems - the value is taken to be relative to the current location and scheme unless its an absolute path/url. Your problem was that you had loaded the html file in your browser from the filesystem(like file://orderForm.html), instead of through the webserver like you should have(http://localhost/orderForm.html), and php must go through the webserver if you want it to be interpreted. the `file://` scheme bypasses the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this

```
<form action="/processorder.php" method="post">
```

Reason why you need to do this is that with this backslash introduced here, the browser will look for the file in the server's directory which for Apache is something like "My Websites", Also there is nothing wrong with your config file of Apache, I know installing Apache is really painful so just relax.